# -ic -ous nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I recently came across a practice problem in my textbook asking me to name a few compounds using -ic and -ous endings. The exact wording is:

**Write the name of each of the following ionic substances, using *-ous* and *-ic* endings to indicate the charge of the cation.**

The first one was $\ce{CoCl2}$. However, cobalt has more than just two oxidization states (3, 2, 0, and -1).

So if it is one of the states in the middle, how do I decide whether to use *-ous* or *-ic*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cobalt may possibly have all those other oxidation states (and others too) for this nomenclature system, we only care about the two [most common oxidation states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt#Compounds) in ionic compounds: $\ce{Co^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Co^{3+}}$. Cobalt(II) compounds would thus be named  *cobaltous* and cobalt(III) compounds would be *cobaltic*. Which is yours?

Comment: Chloride is `-1` and it's Cl2 so Cobaltous. Thanks!

Comment: `-1` as in the charge, not your answer. That was really helpful! +1

Comment: Is there a reference you would recommend for finding the most common oxidization states? I can't find one in my book and online.

Comment: $\ce{Co^3+}$ oxidizes $\ce{Cl-}$.  I know this from personal experience.

Comment: Depending on its ligands Co3+ might oxidize Cl- is closer to the truth